# How to send a message to group of processes in Erlang

Tags: erlang, broadcast

What is the **practical** way to send/broadcast a message to group of processes.

### Explanation:

Users will be gathered upon chatroom `ID`, an `ETS` storage will be used to store user's **Process ID** and **Room ID** `{Pid, Rid}`

#### Question

How do I send a message to all processes paired with **Room ID** synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronously is not possible.

You can get the list of Users Pid in a chatroom Rid using

`ListPid = ets:select(table,[{{'$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',Rid}],['$1']}])`

and you can broadcast the messages with a list comprehension or `lists:foreach/2`

`lists:foreach(fun(X) -> X ! Message end,ListPid)`

Depending on the frequency you are doing search in the ETS, it may be a good idea to store the information as {Rid,Pid} and use the ets:lookup/2 that may be faster.